# How to programmatically hide all the panels in VSCode?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am looking or a way to programmatically hide all the VSCode panels but I couldn't find anything useful in the API: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api

I know I am able to toggle each panel visibility (by using the commands in the code snippet bellow), because a toggle command are available for them, but checking if it's visible or not doesn't look possible.

```js
    vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.toggleActivityBarVisibility");
    vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility");
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.toggleStatusbarVisibility');
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.toggleMenuBar');
```

Would there be a right way (I am also fine with a hacky way) to do it I might be missing?

Comment: Does zen mode work for you?  There is a context key to check that `inZenMode`.

Comment: Alternatively, in my quick testing: `"when": "!activePanel && !sideBarVisible"` seems to work to indicate both the Panel and SideBar are closed.  But there doesn't seem to be a corresponding `statusBarVisible` or `statusBarIsOpen` or `statusBarActive`.

Comment: @Mark I read about the when clause, but only in the context of shortcuts. Is there any way to make use of it programmatically? I need to automatically run this script during startup, a shortcut won't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following commands are available to close, regardless of its visibility, the sidebar and the panel (the word "panel" in VSCode means [this specific widget](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/ux-guidelines/panel)) while I could not find the commands for the activity bar and the status bar.

- `workbench.action.closeSidebar`
- `workbench.action.closePanel`

---

FYI, there are many undocumented commands in VSCode.
I sometimes try to grep with some words on the source code to find such commands, for example, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/search?q=closePanel